# Can not read configurations from vault in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, vault, spring-vault

I am trying to read two simple values from vault in spring boot app. no success and I do not know why. here is my code:

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaultdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>vaultdemo</name>
    <description>vaultdemo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

VaultConfiguration.java:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "knf")
public class VaultConfiguration {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public VaultConfiguration(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

VaultdemoApplication.java :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(VaultConfiguration.class)
public class VaultdemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(VaultdemoApplication.class, args);
        VaultConfiguration bean =  context.getBean(VaultConfiguration.class);
        System.out.println(bean.getUsername());
        System.out.println(bean.getPassword());
    }

}
```

application.properties :

```
spring.application.name=spring-boot-hashicorp-vault-sample
spring.cloud.vault.token=hvs.blomXkLGAvs6sXTHcLFYgbqb
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.uri=http://127.0.0.1:8200
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.backend=secret
```

image of the values in vault:

[image: key-values in vault]

When I run the app It prints null for username and password.
Any ideas to make it work?

Comment: The [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/reference/vault/propertysource.html) allows you to use VaultPropertySource to expose the content of your vault to the Spring Environment which you can use as an alternative solution to get and instantiate the contents of your VaultConfiguration class

Comment: Oh, I managed to find a Spring tutorial that also uses @ConfigurationProperties annotation to interact with the Vault. Can you try to follow all the steps, I m thinking you might have missed something? https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/

Comment: Are you sure to have port twice in your config?

Comment: Issue solved. it was my own mistake actually. thanks for the comments and suggestions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the issues.
First, My packaging was POM. My mistake is that I changed the packaging to POM to test something else, but I forgot to edit it again. My app did not even read the application.properties file. in target/classes folder there was no properties file. so I changed it to jar and also changed the application.properties to application.yml.
its working fine now.

my application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  config:
    import: vault://
  cloud:
    vault:
      uri: http://127.0.0.1:8200
      token: hvs.blomXkLGAvs6sXTHcLFYgbqb
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
      scheme: http
```